# Key sub string lookup in Dynamodb/Cassandra type database for geohashes

Tags: database, database-design, cassandra, amazon-dynamodb, gis

I am working on an application that requires a sub string lookup at the start of the string. For example if my data was:

```
a
a
ab
abc
ab
abcd
ac
bcd
bsdwe
...
```

and I queried for `abcdefghi` it would return the rows:

```
a          because  [a]bcdefghi
a          because  [a]bcdefghi
ab         because  [ab]cdefghi
ab         because  [ab]cdefghi
abc        because  [abc]defghi
abcd       because  [abcd]efghi
```

This dataset needs to be highly available and should be able to support hundreds of millions of rows, that that is why I was looking at a NOSQL type database.

For context, I am using this to store geohashes so I can check to see what polygons (geohashes) contain a point (another geohash) at different sizes. Basically, when querying a point, I need to get back all of the polygons that that point is in. Having a query function like the one described above would allow me to do that. Can someone point me in the right direction for how to do the string query mentioned above? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked to https://www.geomesa.org/ ?

Comment: Are you looking for substring matching, or prefix matching? DynamoDB is fine for prefix matching but not suitable if substring matching is a significant query use case.